# Are there any ASP .Net membership managers (FOSS) available?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership

I have a website that uses ASP .Net membership and roles using the SqlMembershipProvider and SqlRoleProvider.  Right now I am only using this for a small section of the site that only 2 people have access to.  The site may expand in the near future and the number of users could grow into the thousands.

My question is, is there any kind of open source administration tool for managing users or am I stuck building my own?  I can't really use the ASP .Net Web Application Administration Tool because, as far as I know, it is only accessible from Visual Studio.  User administration would be handled by our help desk and would need to handle all of the things that the stored procedures in the SQL server provide such as adding users on the customer's behalf, resetting passwords, unlocking users, etc.

I just can't believe that an administration front-end has not been developed to handle these sorts of things and provide more functionality than the ASP .Net Configuration page provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at MyWSAT on CodePlex.

http://mywsat.codeplex.com/

`MyWSAT aka ASP.NET WSAT is a WebForms based Website Starter Kit for the ASP.NET Membership Provider with Forms Authentication. It provides you with all the security features required for a site out of the box so you start focusing on building your pages. It allows you to manage membership users online once your site is deployed. It features complete administrative back-end functionality and designed to manage users, as well as admin pages for users to manage their own user data.`

Comment: This appears to be just what I am looking for.  Thanks, I appreciate the link.